# Settings.System.put work in a activity but not in a service?

Tags: android, service, settings

My Service updates the brightness settings.

the logcat says, that there is no participant? Ok i read about that, but did not understood why?

if i start that command from a button in a activity, there is no problem it works fine?

Is it a problem of the content(resolver)? The data changed, but it does not have an effect.

is there any solution or explanation?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a context, getContentResolver() need an instance of Context.